# Newtonsoft JSON deserializing array with differing object types

Tags: c#, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize different object types inside a json array in the most efficient way possible but I can't really see how this can be done in any sort of straightforward way.  I'm using the Newtonsoft.Json library for parsing.

I have set up a simple example to illustrate the problem I'm trying to solve, the classes I wish to bind to and the JSON format I'm working with is defined below:

```
class Car
{
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
    public String Manufacturer { get; set; }
    public String Colour { get; set; }
    public double EngineSize { get; set; }
    public String Year { get; set; }
}

class Aeroplane
{
    public String Model { get; set; }
    public String Airline { get; set; }
    public int JourneyCount { get; set; }
}

class Ship
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Company { get; set; }
    public int Capacity { get; set; }
    public String YearBuilt { get; set; }
}
```

And here's the JSON I'm trying to bind to these classes.  It's set up as an array with three different nested object types at each position.  Basically each element/index in the array contains three objects, namely a car, aeroplane and ship.

```
{[
  {
    "car": {
      "wheels": 4,
      "manufacturer": BMW,
      "colour": "Black",
      "engineSize": "1.6"
    },
    "aeroplane": null,
    "ship": null
  },
  {
    "car": {
      "wheels": 4,
      "manufacturer": BMW,
      "colour": "Black",
      "engineSize": "1.6"
    },
    "aeroplane": {
        "model": "Dreamliner",
        "airline": "Emirates",
        "journeyCount": 4798
    },
    "ship": {
        "name":"Queen Mary",
        "company":"Cunard",
        "capacity": 890,
        "yearBuilt": 2000
    }
  },
  {
    "car": {
      "wheels": 4,
      "manufacturer": BMW,
      "colour": "Black",
      "engineSize": "1.6"
    },
    "aeroplane": {
        "model": "Boeing 777",
        "airline": "BA",
        "journeyCount": 6158
    },
    "ship": {
        "name":"HMS Diamond",
        "company":"Royal Navy",
        "capacity": 500,
        "yearBuilt": 2010
    }
  }
]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First your json is not valid. To make it valid you need to get rid of the top curly braces.  Also there are some missing quotes. You can use [JSON Lint](http://jsonlint.com/) to validate it. It should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "car": {
            "wheels": 4,
            "manufacturer": "BMW",
            "colour": "Black",
            "engineSize": "1.6"
        },
        "aeroplane": null,
        "ship": null
    },
    {
        "car": {
            "wheels": 4,
            "manufacturer": "BMW",
            "colour": "Black",
            "engineSize": "1.6"
        },
        "aeroplane": {
            "model": "Dreamliner",
            "airline": "Emirates",
            "journeyCount": 4798
        },
        "ship": {
            "name": "Queen Mary",
            "company": "Cunard",
            "capacity": 890,
            "yearBuilt": 2000
        }
    },
    {
        "car": {
            "wheels": 4,
            "manufacturer": "BMW",
            "colour": "Black",
            "engineSize": "1.6"
        },
        "aeroplane": {
            "model": "Boeing 777",
            "airline": "BA",
            "journeyCount": 6158
        },
        "ship": {
            "name": "HMS Diamond",
            "company": "Royal Navy",
            "capacity": 500,
            "yearBuilt": 2010
        }
    }
]
```

You need one more class to wrap car, aeroplane and ship:

```
public class VehicleWrapper
{
    public Car Car { get; set; }

    public Aeroplane Aeroplane { get; set; }

    public Ship ship { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can deserialize it with the following line:

```
List<VehicleWrapper> vehicles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VehicleWrapper>>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Yeah I just realised I pasted in an old copy of the JSON, apologies and well spotted. Thanks I'll try that.